# Apache 2.4 not calling Perl FastCGI Authenticator script

Tags: apache-2.4, perl, mod-fcgid, rhel8

My company is currently trying implement a new Perl FastCGI based login script to work with Apache 2.4's `mod_fcgid` module. Our old one relied on `mod_perl` to do the bridge between Apache's basic authentication and Perl, but `mod_perl` is no longer available in RHEL 8.

After a ton of research over the past 2 weeks, I have been unable to get it to work. I confess my Apache knowledge is quite limited, I'm a programmer and I basically taught myself what I know, so I'm sorry in advance if it's something trivial.

Below is my virtual server configuration, based on [mod_fcgid documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin suporte@ourserver.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/teste_fcgi_autenticador/"

        ServerName teste_autenticacao.ourserver.com

        <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/teste_fcgi_autenticador>
                Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                AddHandler fcgid-script .cgi .pl
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Simple_login"

                #AuthUserFile /var/www/cgi-bin/teste_fcgi_autenticador/.htpasswd
                FcgidAuthenticator /usr/lib64/perl5/Autenticador/autenticador.pl

                Require valid-user
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Running the above without `AuthType` and `AuthName` does appear to work, as the error log shows:

```
mod_fcgid: authenticator requires basic HTTP auth credentials
No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /cgi-bin/teste.pl. Authentication not configured?
```

When I add those tags, the log complains that `AuthUserFile` is missing, implying it is expecting the `.htpasswrd` file instead of my script.

When I try to run this server config with `AuthUserFile`, it works like a charm, but validating the user/password from `.htpasswrd` file instead of my script.

I have also tried to add this configuration to `fcgid.conf`, as follows, using both the old and the new designation, with no success:

```
# This is the Apache server configuration file for providing FastCGI support
# through mod_fcgid
#
# Documentation is available at
# http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

# Use FastCGI to process .fcg .fcgi & .fpl scripts
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl

# Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

# Function that handles authentication
#FastCgiAuthenticator /usr/lib64/perl5/Autenticador/autenticador.pl
FcgidAuthenticator /usr/lib64/perl5/Autenticador/autenticador.pl
```

Here is the Perl script `autenticador.pl` we are trying to run - example taken from [mod_authnz_fcgi documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_fcgi.html) (both the file and the folder it is in have full permissions):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use FCGI;
my $request = FCGI::Request();
while ($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    die if $ENV{'FCGI_APACHE_ROLE'} ne "AUTHENTICATOR";
    die if $ENV{'FCGI_ROLE'}        ne "AUTHORIZER";
    die if !$ENV{'REMOTE_PASSWD'};
    die if !$ENV{'REMOTE_USER'};

    print STDERR "This text is written to the web server error log.\n";

    if ( ($ENV{'REMOTE_USER' } eq "foo" || $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'} eq "foo1") &&
        $ENV{'REMOTE_PASSWD'} eq "bar" ) {
        print "Status: 200\n";
        print "Variable-AUTHN_1: authn_01\n";
        print "Variable-AUTHN_2: authn_02\n";
        print "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Status: 401\n\n";
    }
}
```

Note: we are NOT using `mod_authnz_fcgi`, as it is not available in RHEL 8's Apache 2.4 build. We are currently only using the script - which does work as intended when called from the shell. If you know how to get this module installed and running, please let me know.

System configuration for reference:

Amazon AWS server running RHEL 8

Apache 2.4.37

Perl 5.26.3

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.